# Code fragment starting with a space

Tags: restructuredtext

Is there some trick or workaround that allows me to write a code block that starts with a space in reStructuredText? Something like:

```
  This line is indented
This line is not
```

The naïve attempt:

```
::

    This line is indented
  This line is not
```

obvoiusly doesn't work (the second line is not interpreted as part of the same block. Visually I could obtain the same thing by using a non-breaking space, but then it would affect copy-paste.